# Different values for du and du -h

Tags: command-line, disk-space

On the command line, `du` seems to return twice the numeric value returned by `du -h`.

Apparently, `du -h` resembles the actual file size, so what's the plain `du` value representing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **-h** "Human-readable" output.  Use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte, Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte and Petabyte.

If -h is not given, the sizes are given in 512-byte blocks.

Comment: Right, I missed the blocksize part on the man page. Thanks.